# CakePHP 3: Making sure all model fields are filled before final submission

Tags: validation, cakephp-3.0, form-submit

I have two buttons on my page (with LOADs of fields) - one for saving a Draft and one for final submission.

A user can save a draft multiple times, till all fields are completed and then hits submit. The built-in validators can be set to validate **on create** and **on update** - but updating a draft will also fire on update.

What logic can I implement to ensure that all fields are completed (requirePresence) and validated (correct data types), when final submission button is clicked - and how can I tie these two together?

Thank you.

Comment: When you save the record, you can specify which set of validation rules to use. Simply use a different set for draft than final.

Comment: Thank you Greg. I figured this out shortly after I posted here. If you post your comment as the answer, I'm more than willing to accept :)